# JW Player Version 5 Audtio Only

Tags: jwplayer

I have JW Player version 5 embedded into a webpage.  I am using it for AUDIO only.  Everything works fine in browsers and on android devices.  However, when on an iPad surfing with Safari the audio will not play.  It is set up so that the user has to click the play button in order for the file to start playing.  When you click the button it says something like "Download not available".  I can't provide a link as it is on an internal development server, but this the code that I am using (if it helps).  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
var secondsPlayed, myDuration, pctViewed, isComplete, lastTimeStamp;

window.onload = function () 
{

    myDuration = <%=intTotalLength %>;
    isComplete = false
    lastTimeStamp = 0
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        flashplayer: "js/jwplayer/player.swf",
        file: "<%=strAudioFileName%>",
        controlbar: "bottom",
        height: 20,
        width: 350,
        Duration:<%=intTotalLength %>,
        events: {
            onTime: function (event) {
                secondsPlayed = event.position;
                pctViewed = secondsPlayed / myDuration * 100;
                if (pctViewed > 99.99) {
                    isComplete = true;
                }
            },
            onMeta: function (evt) {
                if ((typeof evt.metadata.duration != "undefined") && (evt.metadata.duration > 0)) {
                    myDuration = evt.metadata.duration;
                }
            },
            onPlay: function () {
                 startTracking();
            },
            onComplete: function () {
                 stopTracking()
            }
        }

    });

}

function startTracking() {
    setTimeout("updateViewData()", 20000);
}

function stopTracking() {
    isComplete = true;
    updateViewData();
}

function updateViewData() {
    if (secondsPlayed != lastTimeStamp) {
        lastTimeStamp = secondsPlayed;

        $.ajax({
            url: "mediatimetracker.asp",
            type: "post",
            data: "ViewId=<%=strViewID %>&SecondsPlayed=" + secondsPlayed + "&IsComplete=" + isComplete,
            success: function (res) {
                if (isComplete == false) setTimeout("updateViewData()", 20000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: Ethan, I will see what I can do to provide you with a link.

Comment: Ethan, I have a secure location that you can check but it will require a username and password.  Can I email you the info?

Comment: Sure, email info [at] longtailvideo [dot] com, thanks!

Comment: Ethan,  Thanks for your help.  We actually figured out that the problem exists on the Clients end of things.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, great. Client issue ;) , np!